# How to change default skin from BlueSpiceSkin in MediaWiki with BlueSpice?

Tags: mediawiki, configuration

In a BlueSpice installation of MediaWiki, the default skin is BlueSpiceSkin and the only other choice offered is Vector.  I would like Vector to be the default for all users, but do not see how to do so.

For now, I've edited the LocalSettings.php to comment out the line near the bottom that loads the BlueSpiceSkin:

```
# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
require_once("$IP/extensions/BlueSpiceDistribution/BlueSpiceDistribution.php");
require_once("$IP/extensions/BlueSpiceFoundation/BlueSpiceFoundation.php");
require_once("$IP/extensions/BlueSpiceExtensions/BlueSpiceExtensions.php");
#require_once("$IP/skins/BlueSpiceSkin/BlueSpiceSkin.php");
require_once "$IP/extensions/TwoFactorAuthentication/TwoFactorAuthentication.php";
```

And after doing so, by default users are on Vector and now additional skins are offered of: Cologne Blue, Modern, and MonoBook but, as expected, BlueSpiceSkin is no longer listed.

Rather than just cut the skin out completely, I'd just like to not have it be the default, plus I'd like it to not hide the 3 other skins that appeared when it was not loaded.

I tried editing `skins/BlueSpiceSkin/BlueSpickSkin.php` at the end to become:

```
$wgDefaultSkin = 'vector';
// 'cologneblue', 'modern', 'monobook',
$wgSkipSkins = array( 'chick', 'common',
    'myskin', 'nostalgia', 'simple', 'standard' );
```

However, I keep getting permission denied when I try to save even though I changed directory and file permissions to each be `777`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to instead edit the LocalSettings.php to be at the end of the file:

```
# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
require_once("$IP/extensions/BlueSpiceDistribution/BlueSpiceDistribution.php");
require_once("$IP/extensions/BlueSpiceFoundation/BlueSpiceFoundation.php");
require_once("$IP/extensions/BlueSpiceExtensions/BlueSpiceExtensions.php");
require_once("$IP/skins/BlueSpiceSkin/BlueSpiceSkin.php");
$wgDefaultSkin = 'vector';
// 'cologneblue', 'modern', 'monobook',
$wgSkipSkins = array( 'chick', 'common',
    'myskin', 'nostalgia', 'simple', 'standard' );
require_once "$IP/extensions/TwoFactorAuthentication/TwoFactorAuthentication.php";
```